# Azure Functions (Typescript) - How can I run a setup/bootstrapper function

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure-functions

I have several functions in my function app. Is there a way to have a setup/bootstrapper function run before all functions? This would be something that maybe sets up some global variables, logging, etc. I'm it would just be an `index.ts` file that gets run before each function.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm doing this using a Higher Order function:

```js
export function withSetup(fn) {
    return (...args) => {
        // Do some setup stuff here
        return fn(...args);
    };
}
```

This works but if you forget to wrap the function it can cause strange issues. I'm curious if there are other answers.